# Can you fetch git commit data using cURL?

Tags: git, curl

I need to fetch the object of an annotated tag (i.e. the annotation message) from a remote repository and so far there doesn't seem to be a command for that (i.e. `ls-remote` provides only the refs but not the annotation) so I'm wondering if there is any other utility or if it's possible to fetch this data with cURL.

This is about the smart protocol as the old dumb seems deprecated on some sites (i.e. on github).

I'm aware that I could clone the repository and get the data I need locally but I'm trying to avoid that. 
I'm aware that github and perhaps other services have proprietary APIs but i'm not interested in that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the "smart" protocol is actually dumber in some respects than the "dumb" protocol. It doesn't allow you to fetch specific objects. You need to clone a branch (depth can be specified)  and then fetch the tags.